# How to get the Number of records in a Data lake File with Logicapp Data Lake connector?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to get the Table data from Azure Database table and upload the same to Data Lake file using logic app. Once the upload is complete, I need to get the number of records present in the Data lake file. Does logic app has any expressions or built-in methods to get the number of records in a Data lake file.

Answer (score 0):

At the data lake store level, there is no notion of records. You can query information about the file such as how many bytes long it is. The concept of records is what is interpreted by application that read it based on the type of data (CSV, JSON etc) and the delimiter that makes sense.

You will need to do this as a separate step before or after saving the file.